# Metodos para llamar Store Procedure desde C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo este metodo para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados

```
    public void EjecutarSP(string sp)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, ConexionBD.con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ConexionBD.Conectar();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ConexionBD.Desconectar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(" Error al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado ", ex);
        }
    }
```

Este método me sirve genéricamente cuando los procedimientos almacenados no reciben ni devuelven ningún valor, quería saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlos genéricos para cuando el procedimiento almacenado recibe y devuelve parámetros, creo que para la parte de devolución puedo utilizar ExecuteReader que me devuelve una tabla y después trabajarla en la aplicacion, pero para la parte de envió de parámetros no se si se pueda hacer algo genérico ya que no todos los procedimientos almacenados reciben la misma cantidad de parametros

Comment: Yo colocaría un parámetro adicional a tu método genérico; el parámetro sería algo así como: `SqlParameterCollection listaParametros`; en tu lógica debes validar que `listaParametros` no sea NULL (y aquí determinas basado en esta condición si ejecutas `ExecuteNonQuery` o `ExecuteReader`), sin embargo **no estoy seguro que esta sea la mejor opción** por eso, el comentario.

Comment: @Mauricio Y como funciona la parte de los nombres de los parámetros cuando pasas la lista?, actualmente los estoy pasando así command.Parameters.AddWithValue("variable", "valor");

Comment: Lee esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23320836/4092887). Suerte.

Comment: Hace tiempo hice una [libreria base](https://github.com/JEnriqueZS/DAL-BaseLibrary) para llamar procedimientos almacenados o ejecutar consultas como texto, quizá te pueda dar alguna luz de como juntar los métodos sobrecargados que tiene la librería y hacerlos genericos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este método te ayudará a ejecutar *Stored Procedures* utilizando tipos de dato genéricos:

```
public IEnumerable<T> EjecutarStoredProcedure<T>(string storedProcedure, string connectionString, SqlParameter[] parameters, Func<SqlDataReader, T> body)
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    using (Connection connection = new Connection())
    {
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateSPConnection(storedProcedure, connectionString);
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            results.Add(body(reader));
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Ahora, para poder hacer una llamada al método sería de la siguiente forma:

```
public IEnumerable<UserEntity> GetUser()
{
    try
    {
        return ProceduresExecution.Instance.EjecutarStoredProcedure<UserEntity>("NombreStoredProcedure",
            GlobalData.ConnectionStringDefault,
            new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@inUserId", 123),
                new SqlParameter("@OtroParametro", "OtroParametro")
            },
            reader =>
            {
                return new UserEntity
                {   
                    //En esta sección van todas las propiedades de la Entidad UserEntity y ["Aqui"] van mapeados a los nombres de las columnas que recuperaste en la consulta de base de datos
                    UserId = (int)reader["UserId"],
                    Nombre = reader["Nombre"].ToString()
                    UserTypeId = (int)reader["UserTypeId"]              };
            });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener el usuario" + ex.message);
    }
}
```

Al enviar al método

```
new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter("@inUserId", 123),
    new SqlParameter("@OtroParametro", "OtroParametro")
},
```

Estás enviando todos los parámetros deseados para que finalmente los puedas recibir en automático en el tipo de la clase que deseas de forma genérica.

Comment: Muchas gracias,  esto es lo que necesitaba, el metodo EjecutarStoredProcedure me quedo claro. Solo una consulta mas, porque tenes dos return en el getUser, yo siempre lo uso al final, ponerlo al principio debe ser otra manera de usarlo, pero no entiendo porque esta dos veces y el reader reader =>. Gracias! @Flxtr

Comment: ya pude enviar los parámetros al procedimiento almacenado, lo único que me falta es poder pasar el reader a algún tipo de dato que pueda devolver, ya que no puedo devolver el SqlDataReader porque cuando cierra la conexión se pierden los datos, creo que debería volverlo a una lista generica

Comment: Si notas, antes de que se cierre el `Reader` se agrega el contenido a una clase, esa clase es la que posteriormente vas a manipular como objeto

Comment: Que diferencias habría entre pasar el SqlDataReader a una ListaGenerica como lo haces vos o pasarlo a un DataTable?, hay alguna diferencia por la cual me convenga mas una que otra?, o es lo mismo?. Pregunto porque para pasarlo al DataTable se me hace mas facil ya que solo tengo que usar DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);

Comment: Ah lo que pasa es que el uso de DataTables es más pesado en cuanto a recursos, por lo tanto es más recomendable utilizar listas

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres podrías usar la clase [Sql Helper](https://github.com/hprez21/Hyrule/blob/master/Hyrule.Data/SQLHelper.cs) que ya tiene los métodos sobre cargados que quieres, u otro es adecuarlo a las necesidades que tienes.

Mira este [tutorial](https://github.com/hprez21/Hyrule), el cual usa dicha clase.

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo a tu respuesta. [Revisa esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para mas información.