# Convertir SqlDataReader en Lista Generica

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

Tengo un SqlDataReader en un método y necesito retornarlo, el problema es que al cerrar la conexión de SQL los datos de SqlDataReader desaparecen, a que tipo de dato debería poder pasarlo para devolverlo?, este es mi codigo

```
static public tipoDato EjecutarSP(string sp, SqlParameter[] parametros)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sp, ConexionBD.con);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parametros);
            ConexionBD.Conectar();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
            ConexionBD.Desconectar();
            return resultado;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(" Error al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado ", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alejandro, la respuesta a tu pregunta puede tener muchas soluciones. Por ejemplo, puedes retornar Dataset, DataTable, XML, Listas genéricas, arreglos, Diccionarios, etc. en fin hay una gran variedad de tipos que puedes retornar. Si puedes dar mas detalles de tu proyecto seria mas fácil dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Si luego vas a necesitar esos datos, en lugar de un `SqlDataReader` utiliza un `SqlDataAdapter` que rellene un `DataTable`y devuelve el `DataTable`

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez Que diferencia habría entre Dataset, Datatable y Listas generias y cual me conviene?, en cuando a mas detalles es lo único que me falta, poder devolver el resultado para poder trabajarlo en el otro metodo

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti, Lo que te conviene depende de la arquitectura del proyecto o incluso de los mismos requerimientos. Por ejemplo si esa información en algún momento debes exportarla a XML de repente lo mas comodo seria usar un Dataset o un DataTable, pero si únicamente lo que necesitas es pasar información de una capa a otra y tu arquitectura maneja "Entidades", entonces posiblemente lo mejor sea usar listas genéricas; y esto es solo por poner un pequeño ejemplo. Realmente no hay una verdad absoluta con respecto a lo que necesitas.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez Claro, lo que necesito es pasar información de una capa a otra, el ExecuteReader me devuelve un SqlDataReader , o sea debería pasarlo a una lista genérica pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti, dentro de tu proyecto tienes alguna Clase con la que puedas mapear el resultado del SqlDataReader como por ejemplo: public class Empleado{.....}. Si es así actualiza tu pregunta con la Clase que deseas retornar y con un ejemplo de lo que retornaría el procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez No, son muchas las consultas que debo realizar así que no siempre se puede mapear, pude resolverlo usando DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);. Luego trabajo con DataTable, mi consulta ahora es si es efectivo asi o es mejor trabajarlo con listas genericas o que diferencias puede llegar a haber

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti Bueno acá te dejo unos vínculos, para que saques tus propias conclusiones: http://clase-publica-abstracta.blogspot.com.co/2013/01/preferir-colecciones-genericas-sobre.html  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa479317.aspx  -  https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-move-datatables

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez Gracias, estuve leyendo, de todas maneras casi no voy a usar entidades con las cuales relacionar el resultado, así que por ahora voy a usar DataTable, pero me sirvió la información por si en algún futuro tengo otras casos, gracias

Comment: Hola @Alejandro, si deseas ejecutar Stored Procedures y almacenar el resultado en un objeto genérico, te recomiendo que leas [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47597/16841), sin duda creo que es lo que estás buscando

Comment: @Flxtr Gracias, esa pregunta tambien a habia hecho yo, es parecida a esta, ya logre resolverlo y califique la respuesta

Comment: Termine usando SqlDataReader readerResultado = command.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable tablaResultado = new DataTable();
                tablaResultado.Load(readerResultado);

Comment: Ah muy bien, vale vale :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que trabajas con strings, create un lista al princpio del metodo.

```
List<string> res = new List<string>()
```

Dentro del reader.read() puedes hacer

```
 while (reader.Read())
    {
    string aux = reader.GetString(0) 
    res.Add(aux);    
    }
```

y de esta forma tienes en la lista res todos los strings.

P.D: estarias cogiendo la primera columna de la consulta, y la estas tratando como un string.

Si quieres tratar mas genericamente, en vez de string crea la lista de tipo object

Si lo quieres tratar como un Datatable lo mejor es usar SQLReader con parametros

```
>       string con = "Data Source = datascource;" +
>                           "Initial Catalog = catalog;" +
>                           "Persist Security Info=True;" +
>                           "User ID=...;" +
>                           "Password=...;" +
>                           "providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;"; SqlConnection connSQL = new SqlConnection(con);
>         tabla = new DataTable();
>         connSQL.Open();
>         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT .... = @par", connSQL);
>         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par", tu_variable);
>         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>         Adapter.Fill(tabla);
```

y en este punto en tabla tienes todos los datos.

Comment: Es que ahí en lo que pasas solo traes un dato, mi consulta es como traer todo

Comment: Hola, puedes especificar un poco mas a que te refieres con "todo", ¿todos los registros? ¿todas las columnas?

Comment: List<TuClase>() listaDeResultados = new List<TuClase>();

Comment: @Veelicus todas las filas y columnas para poder trabajarlas en el método que las devuelve

Comment: @fredyfx No puedo declarar una clase en ese método ya que es algo generico

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti Hola, entonces en tu caso lo mejor es posible que lo trates como un datatable, te lo indico en mi respuesta